# RFC 違反の JSON を RFC 準拠に整形する方法。あるいは許容する方法はありませんか？

Tags: json, jq

## やりたいこと

RFC 違反の JSON を jq で処理したい。あるいは事前に RFC 準拠の JSON に変換したうえで jq で処理したい。

イメージとしては以下のような感じです。

```
jq <何かオプション> '.' invalid.json
```

あるいは

```
<何かツール> invalid.json | jq '.'
```

## 環境

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- jq version 1.3

## 現象

以下のような JSON があります。これは RFC 違反です(末尾のカンマが余計)。よって jq からパースエラーと言われます。

```
% echo '{"foo": "0xFF",}' | jq '.'
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 1, column 16
```

末尾のカンマを削除すれば jq は JSON として解釈してくれます。

```
% echo '{"foo": "0xFF"}' | jq '.' 
{
  "foo": "0xFF"
}
```

## 質問

例えば [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) というサイトでは、入力された文字列が JSON として正しいかどうか判定してくます。誤っている JSON ならばそれを正しい JSON に整形してくれるオプション(「Fix JSON」)もあります。

この「JSON Formatter & Validator」で「Fix JSON」をおこなうのと同じようなことをおこなう方法( *オフラインのツール* )は無いでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Hjson, a user interface for JSON](https://hjson.github.io/) Python実装版は pip でインストール可能です(`pip install hjson`)。質問欄の例の場合は `echo '{"foo": "0xFF",}' | hjson -c | jq '.'` などとします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ためしに hjson をインストールしたところ、期待通りにできました。

Comment: タイトルに含まれている「あるいは許容する方法」についてはJSONを扱う何かしらのツール側での都合になるので、準拠したフォーマットに整形するとは少しアプローチが異なるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: 「あるいは許容する方法」については、jq のオプションに「RFC違反のJSONでも処理してくれる」といったものが無いか、という意図でした。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jq の公式 wiki にある [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) ではいくつかのツールが具体例と共に紹介されていました。

> : Is there a way to have jq keep going after it hits an error in the input file? Can jq handle broken JSON?
>
> A: Yes, though in general, preprocessing (e.g. using hjson or any-json) would be preferable. Also, there are more options if you have jq 1.5. （後略）
>
> （和訳）
> 質問：入力を読んでいる最中にエラーが出ても jq に読ませ続ける方法はありますか？　壊れた JSON を jq に扱わせることはできますか？
>
> 回答：はい。一般的には、hjson や any-json などを使って前処理をするのが望ましいです。また jq 1.5 以降であればいくつかオプションを利用することもできます。（後略）

- hjson
- any-json
- relaxed-json
- strip-json-comments
- jsonlint
- json5

2020年1月現在では、[FAQ ページ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)の一番下に詳細が書かれています。

Comment: ぐは。FAQにありましたか。ありがとうございます。いくつか検討します。

Answer (score 3):

[jsonlint](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint) というPHP製のユーティリティがあるようです。[Ubuntu向けのパッケージ](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/jsonlint) も提供されていますが、お使いのバージョン(14.04.4)だと見つかりませんでした。

参考:
[JSON Valdiator in Ubuntu 16.04 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/876815)

Comment: ありがとうございます。14.04の場合は  python-demjson というパッケージに含まれているようです http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jsonlint.1.html ただ、16.04 以上にも python-demjson パッケージはありますね。これとは jsonlint パッケージも存在していて、まだよく分かっていません。